# Is there something I am missing which means I can only write to firestore locally and not in production with Zeit Now deployed app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, vercel

I am able to write to my firestore db locally without trouble but after I have deployed my next.js app the writing and updating functions dont result in any change on the DB.

I am initialising firebase like so

```
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
const auth = firebase.auth();

export {
    auth,
    firebase
};
```

and my firestore rules are like this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write, update: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I can't find any errors (is there an easy way to see ZEIT now console.log outputs on the server side, right now I am just passing them back in the response).

Any small response would be much appreciated.

Comment: found the error? I have the same.